# Is there an opposite direction equivalent to scrollIntoView method in Android uiAutomator?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I need to scroll from bottom to top until certain text is found, but I cannot understand how to achieve this. I read in the official documentation but so such thing is specified. Am I missing something?

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable#scrollintoview)

Something like this:

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()" +
                ".scrollIntoViewBackwards(new UiSelector().text(\"" + country + "\"))"));
//notice the scrollIntoViewBackwards method I have in mind
```